# Should reputation or badges be used to encourage referring users to StackExchange communities?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, new-users

I just sent out information about the site to 6 acquaintances whose knowledge and expertise I call upon regularly, because I realized that this community is improved by greater activity (assuming that "negative" activity is filtered out).

It made me wonder if it would make sense to award reputation or medals for referrals - the magnitude of the reward being linked to the activity level of those referred to the site.

Is this done?

Comment: It would be great if you would refer some people, but I don't believe there was ever a reputation bonus for referrals. Or a badge, even though that would be a better idea. Would not be easy to prove you referred someone.

Comment: It could just be added as another field on the registration page. My referral would just list my email addy or username as they sign up.

Comment: They could easily lie.

Comment: Sure. But why would they?

Comment: It could be The Community Builder badge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't exist exactly as stated in your question.

There are badges -- [Announcer, Booster and Publicist](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) -- for sharing a link to a post using the `share` button underneath the post.  (More information in the Q&A: [How can I 'try' to get the publicist badge?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/540/26))

On Area 51, you can get both [reputation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for each person that signs up for a site proposal via the "Share this" link on the proposal's page, and [badges](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges) -- Lobbyist, Campaigner and Activist -- if enough people sign up using your referral link.

But on this site, there are no badges for referring people that eventually join the site, despite several feature requests on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), for example:

- [Badges for referral links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16383/badges-for-referral-links)
- [Implement a recruiter badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/implement-a-recruiter-badge)
- [Referral badges for new members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89491/referral-badges-for-new-members)

Given that the blog post about the Announcer, etc. badges is presented as an answer for some of the above Meta SE feature requests, presumably the hope is that people that visit using the referral link will join the site and become productive members.

Comment: I've checked the above feature requests. The recruiter badge is closest to what I had in mind. The difference between that and the Announcer badge, and the reason I'd think that the Recruiter badge would be of more benefit to the community is that while a hot link on Reddit might generate traffic, it doesn't necessarily improve the community whereas a someone I refer to the site who proves to be an active participant demonstrably improves the community through participation and reputation. It could be scaled so that 1 power user gives the same "award" as a greater number of less active users.